# How do I define a type hierarchy using Rust enumerations?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make a compiler in Rust, but I'm having problems understanding how to define a type hierarchy using enumerations. We have for example:

```
enum Thing {
    Animal,
    Plant,
}

struct Plant {
    color: String,
}

enum Animal {
    Dog,
    Cat,
}

struct Cat {
    name: String,
}

struct Dog {
    name: String,
}

let x = Dog { name: john };
```

If I do pattern matching, will `Dog` be considered of `Animal` type (or `Thing` type)? How do I create this type hierarchy using enums and structs? My type hierarchy has many levels of depth.

Comment: As it stands, your types are completely independent of one another. Also, Rust doesn't support the notion of inheritance. I would suggest looking into using traits if you want to have some idea of sub typing.

Comment: You may find https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-do-c-like-inheritance/20545 very interesting.

Answer (score 7):

When you look at this piece of code:

```
enum Thing {
    Animal,
    Plant,
}

struct Plant {
    color: String,
}
```

You see the word `Plant` twice. The important thing to note is that *the two `Plant`s are different, unrelated things.* Just because they have the same name doesn't mean that they represent the same thing, and in fact they don't really have the same name when you take the fully qualified name: the first one is `::Thing::Plant` and the second one is just plain `::Plant`.

If you want to link the two, you will need to make it explicit with:

```
enum Thing {
    Animal(Animal),
    Plant(Plant),
}
```

For more details, you can look at the `IpAddr` example in [the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html#enum-values).

Comment: This is close, but does not directly answer OPs question.

Comment: @Shepmaster OP asked "How do I create this type hierarchy using enums and structs?" This is one way to do it.